# javascript variable as selector in jquery to get specific child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show, css-selectors

I have the following structure in DOM:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child0"></div>
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
    <div class="child4"></div>
    <div class="child5"></div>
            ...
</div>
```

what i try to do in javascript is to show only specific elements and hide the others like this:

```
    showItems(0,3,'.parent'); // show child 0,1,2

    function showItems(offset,limit,component)
    {
        $(component).children().hide();
        for(var i=offset;i<=(offset+limit);i++)
        {
            $(component+':nth-child('+i+')').show();  //!!! does not make them visible
        }

    }
```

any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a space between component and :nth-child. because now you are selecting any element with class "parent" that's also the nth-child.

Answer (score 1):

You should make it easier and use the `.eq()` method instead, like this:

```
function showItems(offset,limit,component)
{
    $(component).children().hide();
    for(var i=offset;i<=(offset+limit);i++)
    {
        $(component).children().eq(i).show();  //this will work!
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answer by Remco, add '>' to make sure you select only one of the immediate childs.

So, one way can write

```
$(component+' > :nth-child('+i+')').show();
```

or even better

```
$(component+' > div:nth-child('+i+')').show();
```

If you do not place the '>' symbol, it can also select the elements inside child divs, if it is present.

Comment: Excellent point and an oversight by me, although he's only hiding direct childs through the .children() call, so in practice it shouldn't have made an impact.

Comment: I fail to see how the second is better than the first. All of the children are `div` elements and if that is known then using `div:nth-child` in place of simply `:nth-child` is actually less efficient, as the system would have to first check to see if the element is a `div` and only then check to see if it is the `:nth-child`.

Comment: Well in this case it doesn't seem to be a problem but suppose if the the parent div had some more content or separator element in the end, then it would be helpful no?

Comment: I would say that it would only be helpful if there were other kinds of child elements. The truth is, the difference in performance between the two is very small. You can see the performance test here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-nth-child-vs-div-nth-child-with-known-child-tags